# How to use int value from Map in switch case?

Tags: java, hashmap, switch-statement

I have a map:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Now I have added some values:

```
myMap.put("east", generateId());
myMap.put("west", generateId());
myMap.put("north", generateId());
myMap.put("south", generateId());
```

Now I am trying to check for matches using switch case:

```
int i = myMap.get("east");
int j = myMap.get("west");
int k = myMap.get("north");
int l = myMap.get("south");
switch (myId) {
    case i:
        break;
    case j:
        break;
    case k:
        break;
    case l:
        break;
}
```

It says constant expression required at all the cases(i, j, k, l). How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can't. The `case` labels must be compile-time evaluable constant expressions, and the values of `i` etc. are only known at run-time.

Use a series of `if` `else` statements instead.

`if (myId == i){` etc.

Comment: Isn't there any other way by using switch?

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi Do you know the values of `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` before you run the program? Your answer to that question is the answer to your question.

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi Honestly, don't force trying to use a switch; they really aren't that great outside of a few select use cases. They just bloat up your code. Use them when you know every possible option at compile time, like if you're using an enum. If you *really* wanted to use a switch, replace your Map with an enum; it makes more sense for your use case anyway since you will never add new directions.

Comment: @ Carcigenicate I will look into it

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi If you have a static amount of options, and your only representinf each option with a number, just use an enum. It will significantly simplify things.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can only use values in switch case, not variables, you must change your code:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(myMap.size());
set.add(new Integer(myMap.get("east")));
set.add(new Integer(myMap.get("west")));
set.add(new Integer(myMap.get("north")));
set.add(new Integer(myMap.get("south")));

if (set.contains(new Integer(myId))) break;
```

You can use `Set` to help you with checking (works in `O(1)`, and there is less code). Also, switch is not OOP so don't use it...

Comment: I will try your solution

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain you have your map the right way around?

```
    Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put(generateId(), "east");
    myMap.put(generateId(), "west");
    myMap.put(generateId(), "north");
    myMap.put(generateId(), "south");
    switch (myMap.get(1)) {
        case "north":
            break;
        case "south":
            break;
        case "east":
            break;
        case "west":
            break;
    }
```

Comment: what if generateId() returns same number for two records?

Comment: @AdnanIsajbegovic - Then the second `put` will overwrite the first.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I will try it

Answer (score -3):

values used for `case` statements must be constants, meaning they must be unable to be changed throughout the statement. You can fix this problem by making your one-letter variables `final`.

Comment: @Zircon This answer doesn't work. They must be **compile-time** constants, which these variables are not even if they are declared final.